# weekly wise dates selected in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My tried query

how can i get the current week dates in mysql query ?

```
SELECT WShipDate FROM `pipo_orders` where WEEKOFYEAR(`WShipDate`) >= WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())

WShipDate
2015-01-10
2015-01-19
2015-01-08
2014-12-25
2014-01-05
2015-01-01
```

My expected output is

```
2014-01-05
2015-01-08
2015-01-10
```

want to get the weekly dates using mysql query.Is it possible ?

Comment: your expected output is inconsistent with the comparison operator in the where clause for starters. try running that query without the single quotes... see what happens

Comment: same result there is not my expected output

Comment: execute SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(WShipDate),WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()), WShipDate  FROM pipo_orders to see what is being compared - might tell you something?

Comment: paste the full query

Comment: SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(WShipDate),WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()), WShipDate FROM pipo_orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

From below query you can get your ouput try this

```
<?php 
 $weekstartday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('monday this week'));
 $weekendday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('sunday this week')); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `pipo_orders` WHERE `WShipDate` between '$weekstartday' and '$weekendday'";

?>
```